# how to get html string from NSAttributedString in iOS

Tags: html, ios, objective-c

I am using `UITextview` in my app. And I have set allowsEditingTextAttributes property to YES in order to show images and formatted text if user copy pasted from browser into textView and working fine.

I want to retrieve the content back as html from `UITextView`, is there any way to get it? (I can achieve it using `UIWebView` but I need to use `UITextView` only)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no API provided by Apple to do what you want. You need to get the attributed text as an `NSAttributedString` from the `UITextView` and convert it to HTML. There are open-source projects for this however, for example [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText/blob/develop/Core/Source/DTHTMLWriter.m). If you're not looking for very advanced features, you might also be able to build this yourself, just by looping through the string's characters and analyzing the style attributes.

EDIT: Actually, there is an API to do this now! You can use `NSAttributedString`'s  [`dataFromRange:documentAttributes:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/dataFromRange:documentAttributes:error:), passing `NSHTMLTextDocumentType` as the requested document type.
Cheers!

Example (in Swift, can be done similarly in Objective-C):

```
//Grab the attributed string, convert it to HTML data
let data = try self.textView.attributedText.dataFromRange(
  NSMakeRange(0, self.textView.attributedText.length),
  documentAttributes: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType]
)

//Convert the UTF-8 data to a string, display it in the text view
self.textView.attributedText = NSAttributedString(
  string: NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String
)
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried with that (I mean dataFromRange:documentAttributes:error:), but it's not working properly..

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working properly'? I tried it myself and it works on my side. Check my initial answer, I added an example.

Comment: if pasted content has images and result string not containing img tags containing anchor tags instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at this repository: https://github.com/IdeasOnCanvas/Ashton

To read:

```
AshtonHTMLReader.h

 - (NSAttributedString *)attributedStringFromHTMLString:(NSString *)htmlString;
```

And to writer:

```
AshtonHTMLWriter.h

- (NSString *)HTMLStringFromAttributedString:(NSAttributedString *)input;
```

See if it can help you.

Comment: This repository does not convert NSTextAttachment to img tag in html.